# Solve recurrence relation - t(n)=(n-1)*t(n-1)

Tags: recurrence-relations

How can I solve the following recursive relation:

```
t(n)=(n-1)*t(n-1)
```

where the base case is

```
t(1)=1
```

Is it okay just saying that:

```
t(2)=1!
t(3)=(3-1)t(2)=2!
t(4)=(4-1)t(3)=3!
t(5)=4!
and so on...t(n)=(n-1)!
```

and after prove this by induction?
Any ideas?

Comment: With an appropriate "prove by induction" it looks like you've got the right idea.  Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have observed something correct, that $t(n)=(n-1)!$. It's not a proof yet though and making a table doesn't really make progress towards a proof, beyond being able to have a reasonable hypothesis to prove.

All you need to note is that
$$t(1)=0!$$
and then it's clear that if $t(n)=(n-1)!$ then $t(n+1)=n!$, since $t(n+1)=n\cdot t(n)$ which would be $n\cdot (n-1)!=n!$.

Answer (score 1):

for $n \ge 1$
$$
\frac{t(n+1)}{t(n)} = n  
$$
so
$$
t(n+1) = \prod_{k=n}^1 \frac{t(k+1)}{t(k)} = \prod_{k=n}^1 k = n!
$$